# Hibernate - Table or view doesnt not exist error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am trying to save an object in database using hibernate. When I run the code for the first time with a new table name it throws below error, but when I run it second time it works perfectly fine-

```
    INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@61ce23ac] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
Sep 01, 2016 3:51:18 AM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl handleException
WARN: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlString(SchemaDropperImpl.java:374)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaDropperImpl.java:359)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.dropFromMetadata(SchemaDropperImpl.java:241)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.performDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:307)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:490)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:710)
    at org.sf.main.SessionFactoryBuilder.getSessionFactory(SessionFactoryBuilder.java:26)
    at org.sf.main.SessionFactoryBuilder.main(SessionFactoryBuilder.java:36)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:951)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:195)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:1036)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1336)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeInternal(OracleStatement.java:1916)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.execute(OracleStatement.java:1878)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.execute(OracleStatementWrapper.java:318)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:49)
    ... 13 more
```

Here is my code-

```
    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

            configuration.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
            configuration.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect");
            configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@somehost:1521:orcl");
            configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "username");
            configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "password");
            configuration.setProperty("show_sql", "true");
            configuration.setProperty("hibernate.default_schema", "somechema");
            configuration.setPhysicalNamingStrategy(new HelloWorldNamingStrategy());
            configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Census2010.class);

            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
            SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build()); 

            return sessionFactory;
        }

        public static void main (String[] args) {
            Census2010 obj = new Census2010();
            obj.setData(100000L);
            obj.setVariable("Population");

            SessionFactory factory = getSessionFactory();
            Session session = factory.openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(obj);
            session.getTransaction().commit();

            factory.close();

        }
```

Here is my Entity class-

```
    import javax.persistence.Column;

    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.Table;

    @Entity
    @Table
    public class Census2010 {
        @Id
        @Column(name="VARIABLE")
        private String variable;

        @Column(name="DATA")
        private long data;

        public String getVariable() {
            return variable;
        }

        public void setVariable(String variable) {
            this.variable = variable;
        }

        public long getData() {
            return data;
        }

        public void setData(long data) {
            this.data = data;
        }
    }
```

Here is the NamingStrategy class-

```
import org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.Identifier;
import org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl;
import org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment;

public class HelloWorldNamingStrategy extends PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final String tableName = "A_12345_P";

    @Override
     public Identifier toPhysicalTableName(Identifier name, JdbcEnvironment context) {
         return new Identifier(tableName, true);
     }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You have "show_sql" property set to "true" and the error is regarding "Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement". Can you, please, provide generated DDL from your logs? DDL statement for your entity's table should appear before the exception.

Answer (score 1):

When you set the hbm2ddl.auto property to true in hibernate.cfg.xml file, you are asking the Hibernate framework to create all the tables corresponding to the objects that you're trying to save and then save the objects.

But, prior to creating the tables, hibernate first tries to drop the tables assuming that they exist in the database.

So when you're running your application for the first time, since the tables doesn't exist in the database, you're facing the error. When you run your program from next time, you'll not see the above error, as the tables exist and hibernate will be able to drop them successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that "somechema" in the sentence  `configuration.setProperty("hibernate.default_schema", "somechema");` is the correct schema?

If it isn't, it won't find the table or view.

Another option is to use annotations, for instance:

```
@Table(schema = "YOURSCHEMA", name = "Census2010")
```

For more information: https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/jboss4guide/r2/html/ch13.html

Comment: schema is correct. the problem is happening when I am running for the first time with a new table name. Second time with the same table name it runs fine.

Comment: @rufy Even I face the same issue. Where you able to find a solution for this problem?

Comment: if you use @Table(schema = "YOURSCHEMA", name = "Census2010") you get the same error?